# How to actually "present a template chooser before calling the importHandler"?

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, uikit

The sample code for UIDocumentBrowserViewController has a comment in `documentBrowser:didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler:` that says *Optionally, you can present a template chooser before calling the importHandler*.

But how? If I instantiate a view and its controller to use for selecting a template, and call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on it, the code doesn't wait for the presented view to be dismissed, but continues happily on. So how can I wait for the the user to select a template in the presented view?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The trick was to realize that there is no need to call the importHandler block already in the `documentBrowser:didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler` method. You can store the block in an instance variable of the object you use to select a template (in my case, an instance of a class derived from UICollectionViewController), present that dialog, return, and then call the stored importHandler block much later in the suitable method of that template selection class, in my case the `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

See [code here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/online/commit/?id=296e0eb8034c62a4266bb595d01e6d3fb1043730)